# How can I perform clean up actions upon closing a view in Kotlin/TornadoFX?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have been searching the docs and IDE autocomplete suggestions and cannot figure this out. The closest I have found is onDelete(), and it is not working the way I envision.

I just need a way to run some clean up code when a view is closed.

Here is a failed attempt using the simple example from the docs.

```
import tornadofx.*

class MyApp: App(MyView::class)

class MyView: View() {
    // this does not print when the window is closed
    override fun onDelete() {
        super.onDelete()
        println("Print on close!")
    }
    override val root = vbox {
        button("Press me")
        label("Waiting")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<MyApp>(args)
}
```

Another failed attempt per a suggestion below:

```
import tornadofx.*

class MyApp: App(MyView::class)

class MyView: View() {
    // "Closing" is never printed when closing this view"
    override fun onDock() {
        currentWindow?.onHidingProperty()?.onChangeOnce {
            println("Closing")
        }
    }
    override val root = vbox {
        button("Press me")
        label("Waiting")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<MyApp>(args)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using this in my project right now. `setOnCloseRequest` is my go to!

```
override fun onDock() {
    currentWindow?.setOnCloseRequest {
        println("Closing")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onDelete` is a callback for the `Workspace` in TornadoFX, and will be called if you click the `Delete` button in the Workspace when that View is active. What you can do is override `onDock` and add a once change listener to the hiding property:

```
override fun onDock() {
    currentWindow?.onHidingProperty()?.onChangeOnce {
        println("Closing")
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and it also did not work. See original question for code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for cleanup code when closing the application, another option that works for child views/fragments/controllers is an FXEvent that's fired on close.  The event is defined like this:

```
object ApplicationClosingEvent : FXEvent()
```

In the main `App`, I override `stop()` so that the event is fired:

```
override fun stop() {
    fire(ApplicationClosingEvent)
}
```

Since `stop()` is running on the application thread, the event is fired and handled synchronously.  Finally, in each view/fragment/controller you can subscribe like so:

```
subscribe<ApplicationClosingEvent> {
    // Clean-up code goes here
}
```

The primary benefit of using an event instead of a window callback is that you can have many different views subscribing to it, rather than a single window callback.